# Close Resource violation in Sonar

Tags: java, database, database-connection, sonarqube

In my Dao classes, for closing db resources I have written a small function which takes in ResultSet, Connection and Statement objects and closes it.

I call this from finally block of each DB access method that I have. But Sonar is showing these as violations like:

```
Ensure that resources like this Statement object are closed after use
```

Is there any way to let Sonar know that these are handled?

Profile used is 'Sonar Way'

Comment: this is the [sonar](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/pmd:CloseResource?layout=false) rule. Compare this with what you've done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This rule is brought by PMD into Sonar, and it is quite basic: it just checks if there's a "myResource.close()" call in the finally block. Full stop. If you're extensively using your "small function", then you should probably consider deactivating this rule as it will generate too many false positives.

You could also try to activate Findbugs rules that may be more intelligent. See those rules on [our Sonar demo instance - Nemo.](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/rules_configuration/index/7?searchtext=close&plugins%5B%5D=findbugs&priorities%5B%5D=&rule_status=ACTIVE&inheritance=&commit=Search)

Comment: I think I will live with the false positives than turning this off.

Comment: You may also add a //NOPMD comment (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.4/suppressing.html)

Comment: Note that it does these kind of checks purely based on the name of the class. If you have your own ResultSet -which may not even have a close method!- the warning is triggered.